# How can I make alphanumeric auto increment id in php

Tags: php, cakephp

Can somebody guide me how I will create alphanumeric id such as AAA001 in php when passing 1.
Both number & character will auto increment.

Comment: duplicate!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000979/alphanumeric-increment-a-string-in-php-to-a-certain-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
function increament($string){
    $string = preg_split('/(\d+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $str = $string[0];
    $num = $string[1];
    $num++;
    if($num>999){
        $str++;
        $num = 000;
    }
    return $str.$num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 'AAA001';
echo $id++;
```

Every time you use `echo $id++;` it will return the next one in the sequence.

Testing Environment:

```
<?php

$id = 'AAA000';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100100; $i++) {
    echo $id++;
}
echo '<br />';
echo $id;

?>
```